# Bash quotes command not found

Tags: bash

I copied and running the command on my ubuntu 18.04 from here
https://kite.com/linux/  but got an error like:

```
$ bash -c “$(wget -q -O – https://linux.kite.com/dls/linux/current)”
bash: “”: command not found
$ type quote
quote is a function
quote ()
{
    local quoted=${1//\'/\'\\\'\'};
    printf "'%s'" "$quoted"
}
```

Any suggestions of the error?

Comment: The curly quotes should be plain, straight ASCII quotes: `"`.

Comment: Did you copy the command from a document or web page? Many times ASCII double quotes are shown as "curly quote" characters in documents so you have to watch for that.

Comment: Copy paste `bash -c "$(wget -q -O – https://linux.kite.com/dls/linux/current)"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably copied and pasted that from some word processor or website that turned the straight, regular, ASCII quotes `"` into pretty, curly Unicode quotes `“ ”`. Bash doesn't understand those. Just type them in by hand to fix the problem.